# Mapcall out in IOS5 with storyboard

Tags: iphone, sdk, mapkit, storyboard, callouts

I am working on an iphone app in IOS5 that user storyboards.  I have created a storyboard that uses mapkit with annotation callouts. I was able to wire up push segues for buttons and table row selections using the Storyboard editor.  I have experience with custom callouts in MapKit, but can not figure out how to push a view controller that is defined in a storyboard from the callout.  I was going to use `[self.navigationController pushViewController:abc animated:YES]`, however, to do this I need to either get the view controller from the storyboard or initialize a new viewcontroller.  I don't have access to the NIB name since there is no NIB name.  How do I get access to an instance of a `ViewController` defined in a storyboard? Is there some way to use the  Storyboard editor to wire PUSH Seques to a custom map annotation callout?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just found a link that explained how to Instantiate a ViewController in Storyboard:

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
myViewController *myVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];

This worked. I was able to push the view controller once I instantiated it using this code.  My problem is solved.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer to the question, and then accept your answer.  It's ok to accept your own answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create segues between view controllers that are programmatically performed by control-dragging from one view controller to the other. Then in the `MKMapViewDelegate` method, `- (void)mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:`, you can programmatically perform a segue as long as you have given the segue an identifier in the storyboard.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    // I've chosen to pass the annotation view as the sender here.
    // I'm assuming this view controller will be configured with data that
    // is backing the annotation view. By passing the view, you will be able
    // to inspect it and it's backing annotation in `prepareForSegue:sender:`
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowSomeViewController" sender:view];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a button and performed by control dragging it to the view controller. After that I use hidden property of the button to make sure it's hidden. You can't just control dragged a mapview to another view controller. You got to use a button for that. Make sure that you give your segue an identifier.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:view];
}
```

Comment: how do I use this and pass some data across to the segue? I tried using prepareForSegue or even shouldPerformSegue ...but seems to by pass these two methods